# Create a public access API in Perl

Tags: database, perl, api

I want to create an API to allow access to a database, which I will be able to write various front-ends for and then access via HTTP. Much in the same way that this service works:
http://www.askgeo.com/#web-api

I assume I will need to create a server type application, that will listen for specific requests and then return the relevant data. And I am looking to write it in Perl

Can any one point me in the direction that I should be looking? What modules would work best? Or any online resources/tutorials that might help get me started?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Why not use something ready? E.g. CouchDB, a document-oriented database, has RESTful API, embedded server and Perl bindings.

Comment: There's a ridiculous amount of modules that solve your problem. Web frameworks are currently *en vogue*, so everyone and their dog has written one, or pieces thereof (try CPAN search "router" to see what I mean). You have to be much, much more specific to get an unbiased reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any server side solution you like. If you don't have preferences try modern one. Below are examples of a server side apps that solve similar task using [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) framework. Take a look also at the [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) and [Catalyst](http://www.catalyst-framework.org/) frameworks. There is a lot of buzz around these, but there are more on CPAN.

[This Mojolicious::Lite app is a simple search interface for the Apache Solr using JSON REST interface.](https://github.com/saiful76/S3)

Here is another example - [A working prototype of a RESTful service for notes management](http://github.com/koorchik/FastNotes-Proto). This is also Mojolicious based app, but is not Lite app, so more than one file and a little bit different syntax. Still code is very simple and readable.